# get WEEK_OF_YEAR in ISO 8601

Tags: java, android, calendar, iso8601

I try to get the "week of year", so the question is basically that I use this code to obtain the week of year but this give me wrong week.
for example today is 27/04/16 so this code brings me 18 but I search online and  the real week is 17.
Whats I need to change in my code to get the week 17 ?

I try this..

```
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());  
    weekOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

And this.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.setTime(new Date());  
    weekOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

In Wikipedia 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week

April   have this weeks 14 to 17
May 18 to 22

This code is in Java 7 Android.
Help me. please.

Thanks

Comment: This is just because of differences in your time zone with calendar's default time zone. Set calendar time zone to yours.

Comment: This give me 17, are you trying this with a real device ?

Comment: Yes this is in real device

Comment: The week number may be locale dependent.

Comment: Week of Year is Locale dependent. You can set it like : DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); Date mydate = sdf.parse("27/04/2016");Calendar mycalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US); mycalendar.setTime(mydate );

Comment: calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7);
won't help me.

Answer (score 3):

So, the answer is use the German Locale to get the Week 17 of the year. In the ISO8901.

```
Calendar calDe = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
calDe.setTime(new Date());
weekOfYear = calDe.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  The first week starts on the first Monday in any given year